# Aligning SVG polygons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list with all our team members.

In the design there are 15 different shapes, which fit into each other. So in the perfect situation you would have:

```
|shape1|shape2|shape3|shape4|shape5|

|shape6|shape7|shape8|shape9|shape10|

|shape11|shape12|shape13|shape14|shape15|
```

But the width of that section is 100% so what happens is:

```
|shape1|shape2|shape3|shape4|shape5|shape6|shape7|

|shape8|shape9|shape10|shape11|shape12|

|shape13|shape14|shape15|shape1|shape2|
```

So what happens is that shape 6 floats next to 5. But that shape6 should be shape1 again. Because that would fit.

So it would be

```
|shape1|shape2|shape3|shape4|shape5|shape1|shape2|

|shape6|shape7|shape8|shape9|shape10|

|shape11|shape12|shape13|shape14|shape15|
```

**What I basicly need is that every LI element next to a LI element with shape5 turns into a shape1 instead of shape6.**

the shapes are added through svg elements(this x 15)
***HTML***

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <clipPath id="polygon-1">
          <polygon fill="#939598" points="183,172.776 89.16,172.776 -6.231,189.785 -0.174,1.02 170.255,37.688 "/>

    </clipPath>
</svg>
```

***CSS***

```
.team article.image-shape.polygon-1{
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#polygon-1);
}
```

I am not quit sire how to tackle this problem. If you guys have any suggestions I could look into, it would be very helpful.

**What have I been trying?**

I have been counting the LI elements within the UL and adding the 6th one class one, but obviously that isn't working when you are scaling down because you would get:

```
|shape1|shape2|shape3|shape4|shape5|

|shape1|shape7|shape8|shape9|shape10|

|shape11|shape12|shape13|shape14|shape15|
```

Comment: Something similar to this http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2011/01/ul-count-li-elements-display-in.html ?

Comment: @Dipaks No sorry, not exactly what I'm loking for. Thats adding a class to every 6th element, but when its next to my 5, it should be a 1. Thanks for the afford anyway :)

Comment: Can you post a JSfiddle or some actual markup? I get the feeling that your question can be answered if we understand what you're asking.